# How to mark-up telephone numbers on Intranet for Mitel Unified Communicator Advanced

Tags: html, phone-number, telephony, intranet, telecommunication

I am using Mitel Unified Communicator Advanced 2.0 with the Mitel.DialBHO plugin for Internet Explorer. The plugin tries to detect numbers in web pages that are formatted like phone numbers and then overlays a click-to-dial hyperlink.

My question is, how would I go about marking up the phone directory on our intranet to explicitly tell the plugin that something is a phone number? We have three digit extention numbers that we use internally and the plugin won't auto-detect these as dialable numbers.

I have tried the usual markup of `<a href="callto:555">ext 555</a>` and `<a href="tel:555">ext 555</a>`, but neither of these have the desired effect. `callto` tries to launch NetMeeting and `tel` doesn't have a registered program and IE displays an error to this effect.

**TL;DR:**

How do you make a hyperlink (or any other tag with a special attribute) tell Mitel UC Advanced to dial a number when clicked?

**Bonus question**

It strikes me that the Stack Exchange may have a better place to ask this question. Any idea which one would be best?

---

**UPDATE**

So I have found the format I need to use it `<a href="DialFromUC://{number}/">{number}</a>`, but it won't accept 3 digit numbers. Unified Communicator will open, but says that it received an "Invalid Command".

Sending it a fully formed phone number works, but if I convert our internet three digit number to the equivelent external number, it uses an outside line instead of routing it internally.

Any way of sending it a three digit number?

Comment: Hi Iain, just wondering where you got the Mitel.DialBHO plugin from? I can not find it any where.

Comment: Hi Andrew, it is bundled with the Unified Communicator Advanced installer. [See this image](http://i.imgur.com/Iug4Pdz.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to dial an internal number from Mitel Unified Communicator, the format is as follows (where 555 is your desired extention number).

```
<a href="DialFromUC://ext.555/">Click here to dial me!</a>
```

Comment: the correction is DialFromUCA://ext.555/ 
the letter `A` is forgotten at the end of `UCA`.

Comment: Iain, somehow this command stopped working for me recently and `dialfromuca://ext.7724/` translates to dial this number on UCA `03987724` for some reason. If you use UCA as well, would you be able to test this and let me know. Thanks

Comment: It's been a long time since I've worked with Mitel UC and I'm no longer with the organisation that had that setup. However, I think the "ext." in my original answer just turned out to be treated as padding by UC. Perhaps in later versions, the app attempts to resolve letters into the correct numbers on the keypad (ext becomes 398). Maybe try using characters that don't resolve on the keypad like `dialfromuca://....7724/` or `dialfromuca://!!!!7724/`

Comment: Thanks for your reply Iain. That's exactly what I suspected. Atm I'm doing only the number after the slashes like //4410 and it works as we use this url inside our organization.